# How to Add current i's value of for loop into an empty array state in react functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

```
    const [btn, setBtn] = useState([]);
    let newArray = []
    for (let i = 1; i<=10; i++) {
      newArray.push(i);
      console.log(btn);
      setBtn([...btn,...newArray])
    }
```

- i have tried to add newArray to state by using the spred operatar but this will result into an infinite loop and my react app is crashed and after geeting the 1 to 10 value in my btn array i need to use loop over my btn array state.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put it inside `useEffect`

```
const [btn, setBtn] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => { 
    const newArray = []
    for (let i = 1; i<=10; i++) {
      newArray.push(i); 
      setBtn([...btn,...newArray]) 
    }
}, [])
```